# Problem with AWK inside bash

Tags: 14.04, bash, awk

Hello there long history short: I'm trying to create a script to run through CI server to kill a specific process.

So searching over the internet I found out this command:

```
myuser@server:/home/myuser# ps -ef | grep someUniqueText | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
5263
```

When I run it in the console it returns me exactly what I need (`5263`), so I created this bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

PROCESSNAME=$1
PID=$(ps -ef | grep $PROCESSNAME | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}');

echo $PID;
```

When I execute it as:

```
myuser@server:/home/myuser# ./killProcess.sh somename
5263 4587 1236
```

The bash script returns 3 numbers being the first the process I need and I have no idea what the other two are, **Why?** o.O

PS.: I'm using `echo` to test it first, I will change it to `kill -9`

Comment: Are you aware of the (exising) [`killall`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/killall.1.html) tool?

Comment: Probably the script finds itself because `somename` is also part of your commandline.

Comment: @PerlDuck No, I was not aware of killall (what defines a process name?). And, for your second comment, doesn't explain why it runs fine in the command line though

Comment: Also [`pgrep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/pgrep.1.html) and [`pkill`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/pkill.1.html)

Comment: For debugging, comment out the `awk` part of the pipeline to see what ps and grep are finding.

Comment: @glennjackman will return to you in a minute, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @glennjackman It turns out that PerlDuck was right it is listing my own script also, and more, it is listing it twice

Comment: @PerlDuck you were right it is listing my own script because someName is passed as argument, is there a way to solve it within this command? Thanks

Comment: You could also grep away `$0` – which is the script's name as you call it, i.e. including the `./` part, if present: `PID=$(ps -ef | grep $PROCESSNAME | grep -v grep | grep -v $0 | awk '{print $2}');`. But `killall somename` would also work. There's even a _preview_: `killall -s 0 -v somename`. It "sends" signal 0 which simply checks whether the process exists but doesn't actually send a signal. The process won't even notice.

Comment: @PerlDuck Yeah, just figured it out, though I used `grep -v killProcess` instead of `grep -v $0`. Can you add an answer with your suggestion and also your reasoning on the somename being listed as well so I can accept it?

Comment: That's one reason using shell functions is a good way to implement things like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running `./killProcess.sh somename` then a process similar to

```
/bin/bash ./killProcess.sh somename
```

exists and the `ps | grep | grep | awk`-line also finds this one because it has the text `somename` in it. I'm not exactly sure why you get two additional PIDs (and not just one) but I reckon it is some parent/child thingy between `bash` and `killProcess.sh`. In one line the PID shows up as PID and in the other one as PPID.

You can avoid these PIDs by grepping them away based on the script's name. It is stored in `$0`, so

```
PID=$(ps -ef | grep $PROCESSNAME | grep -v grep | grep -v $0 | awk '{print $2}');
```

or (with fewer program calls):

```
PID=$(ps -ef | grep $PROCESSNAME | grep -v -e grep -e $0 | awk '{print $2}');
```

Another (safer) way would be to grep away the script's PID. It is stored in `$$`:

```
PID=$(ps -ef | grep $PROCESSNAME | grep -v -e grep -e $$ | awk '{print $2}');
```

Or do it all in `awk`:

```
PID=$(ps -ef | awk "/$PROCESSNAME/ && !/awk/ && !/$$/ {print \$2}");
```

We need to escape the `\$2` here so it isn't interpreted by the shell but by `awk`. That command means:

If the line contains `$PROCESSNAME` and does not contain `awk` and does not contain our very own PID, then print the second column.

The advantage is (in theory) that this runs faster because only one additional command (`awk`) is required as opposed to 3 greps and an awk.

### But:

All these *greps* and *awks* aren't perfect and you'll always find a situation we haven't thougt of here (like partial matches etc.) For that reason I recommend using one of the already written tools:

- [`killall somename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/killall.1.html)  # to preview, first run `killall -v -s 0 somename`
- [`pgrep somename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pgrep.1.html)    # just list the PIDs
- [`pkill somename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pkill.1.html)    # similar to `killall`

Answer (score 2):

I once implemented a similar idea, as a shell function, that I call `psg` (for "ps|grep")

```
psg() {
    local -a patterns=()
    (( $# == 0 )) && set -- $USER
    for arg do 
        patterns+=( "-e" "[${arg:0:1}]${arg:1}" )
    done
    ps -ef | grep "${patterns[@]}"
}
```

This uses a trick of putting the first character of the pattern in brackets, so you get

```
ps -ef | grep "[s]omename"
```

This allows you to drop the `grep -v grep` part of the pipeline.

If you don't pass any arguments, it uses your username to search for your processes.

Comment: It is not working. It prints nothing. Should the process be running with the user that is calling the script?

Comment: How are you ruining it? It's a shell function so you don't put it in a file and call it like a script: paste it at a shell prompt and call it like `psg somename`

Comment: `s/ruining/running/`

Comment: Ooh... Ok, thanks for clarifying. But that is not what I need. I will be calling this over a ssh command through a CI server (not sure how to do that with your version). I figured out how to fix my script with PerlDuck's help.

Comment: @glenn You did that typo on purpose, didn't you? ;-) I like it.

Comment: autocorrect on my phone often results in hilarity